# Que signifie « le chic de circonstance » ?

Tags: expressions, sens

Dans un livre sur le français québécois, j'ai rencontré une difficulté : l'expression *le chic de circonstance*. Une recherche sur Internet et dans les dictionnaires n'a donné aucun résultat sauf la confirmation que l'expression existe dans la langue française et non seulement dans le langage de l'auteur du livre en question. Je joins le paragraphe entier pour plus de contexte.

[image: Récits d'une passion.]

(Gilles Pellerin, Récits d'une passion.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La locution *de circonstance* signifie en général « qui convient aux circonstances » ou bien « attendu dans ces circonstances ». La définition de [circonstance](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/circonstance) peut être trouvée dans n'importe quel dico, en gros c'est le contexte d'une situation.

Ici « le chic de circonstance » signifie approximativement « le chic qui convient dans certaines situations ».